# How do I add a click event to .append() data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Okay, I've kind of painted myself into a corner, with respect to my jQuery (I'm learning).

In the HTML I have:

```
<div class="folders-hierarchy">
    <ul id="folders-hierarchy"></ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function get_folders_hierarchy () {
        var folder_id = ($(this).attr("data-folder") == false) ? 0 : $(this).attr("data-folder");
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "folders/jq_get_folders_hierarchy/" + 0,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (element) {
                for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                    $("#folders-hierarchy").append('<li data-folder="' + element[i].folder_id + '">' + element[i].name + '</li>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    get_folders_hierarchy();
});
```

While this all works for the first run, I need to add a click event to the unnumbered list item in the .append() function. Sadly, I don't know how.

Just so you know, I'm attempting to create a folder selector, which the unnumbered list is designed to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I tried the .delegate() function again — which is where I failed prior to coming here — and I've figured it out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var folder_id;
    $("#folders-hierarchy").delegate('li', 'click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        folder_id = ($(this).attr("data-folder") == false) ? 0 : $(this).attr("data-folder");
        get_folders_hierarchy(folder_id);
    })
    function get_folders_hierarchy (folder_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "folders/jq_get_folders_hierarchy/" + folder_id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (element) {
                $("#folders-hierarchy").empty();
                if (element != null) {
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        $("#folders-hierarchy").append('<li data-folder="' + element[i].folder_id + '"><a href="#folder">' + element[i].name + '</a></li>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    get_folders_hierarchy(0);
});
```

It was also necessary to .empty() the unnumbered list prior to each loop, to ensure I wasn't just appending one level of folder hierarchy to another.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.on()` to prebind the elements for the future using delgation

```
$('#folders-hierarchy').on('click', 'li', function(){...})
```

Basically this uses event delegation mechanism, you are actually binding the event to the container which will delegate the event to `li` that are added in the future (as well as present now) under this container.

See **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

You should make sure you `'#folders-hierarchy'` is not added dynamically after binding this event and is available all the time in DOM to have the event delegated to its `li` elements. If this is not the container, you want you could go for another container (probably higher up) that will exist in DOM any given point And make sure this is under document.ready

Since you are using older version of jquery you can use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
 $('#folders-hierarchy li').live('click', function(){...})
```

#### [Demo with live](http://jsfiddle.net/J4vWM/)

Comment: I'm getting semantic token errors, which might have something to do with the version of jQuery I'm using; I'm on 1.5

Comment: for 1.5 use `live` but this is deprecated in earlier versions. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I've looked at the code you made. It doesn't make any difference. I've tried removing function get_folders_hierarchy() and the call to it, and it's still producing errors.

Comment: @WayneSmallman i have added demo fiddle in answer if that doesnt work give details of what is the error and try replicate it in a fiddle. You dont need ajax call just use static data like what i have done in the fiddle.

Comment: As I just said, I've looked at the jsfiddle and what you've written is not working when applied to my code, making the assumption that I'm meant to wrap it around my own code. As I said earlier, I'm getting semantic token errors.

Comment: When I use .on() I get: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#folders-hierarchy').on')". When I use .live() nothing happens; no errors, and no initial unnumbered list, which I do get if I don't use the wrapping code.

Comment: Because the whole function is wrapped in your code (which, incidentally, is as far as I got earlier), it prevents the initial unnumbered list from being rendered.

Comment: You are writing this outside the `get_folders_hierarchy` right. it should not be in the loop. Just put it directly under doc ready.

Comment: I've added the code in between $(document).ready(function() and function get_folders_hierarchy (). As I said, when I did that earlier on, it prevents the initial unnumbered list from being rendered, because the click event code blocks it from being executed.

Comment: I dont understand the scenario i just put all your code in the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/T6QvQ/ as it works. Probably see if you can replicate it in a fiddle.

Comment: Okay, I've muddled everything into a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/PL8d4/ ), including some actual JSON data, though I'm not sure if I've done it properly, but I'm sure you can knock it into shape.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Now i got what you are trying to do. Yes this is wrong. You intend to call that function on click of `li` then do http://jsfiddle.net/PHeBB/

Comment: If you dont want to use event delegation or live or anything you can just add click event inline too when appending element. like this:http://jsfiddle.net/dBeEx/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sFuxb/ just set the function reference on the click event not the entire function body and defninsion which should be outside document.ready.

Comment: It's not working. I get "undefined" when I click on each list item.